# Closed Set and Open Set Definitions

Tags: general-topology

As I understand intuitively, a set $\mathcal{S}$ is an open set if for every $x\in\mathcal{S}$, it's possible to find a neighborhood contained in $\mathcal{S}$. According to Wiki, a closed set contains ALL of its limit points. Now what's about the case when a set contains some of it's limit points but not all? As per the definitions, I can have a set which is neither closed nor open. Any clarification?

Comment: You can have a set that is neither closed nor open. The sets $[0,1)$ and $\Bbb Q$ are neither closed nor open in the space $\Bbb R$, for instance. And the set $\Bbb R$ is both closed **and** open.

Comment: Nite that a set that contains some but not all of its limit points can be open: example $(0,1)$. It just can't be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sets are not like windows, they are not open or closed (but never both). They're more like linux: complicated and beyond comprehension at first sight.

Sets can be open, closed, both open and closed at the same time, or they can be neither. They can be the countable union of closed sets or the countable intersection of open sets, and they may have a much more complex structure in this sort of aspect.